# Delphi XE: idHttp & Request.Range, a bug?

Tags: delphi, range, delphi-xe, indy, idhttp

I have Delphi XE. I try to set `Request.Range` of `idHttp` but I cannot do this. Delphi doesn't allow me to do this neither at design time nor at run time.

E.g. I set `'6000-'` in a design time -> a property gets empty all time.

I do (in a thread):

```
Downloader.Request.Range:=(IntToStr(DFileStream.Position) + '-');
synchronize(procedure begin showmessage(Downloader.Request.Range) end);
```

`showmessage(Downloader.Request.Range)` shows me nothing (an empty string).

I checked a request in HTTPAnalyzer -> my program doesn't send a range.

A checked this behavior in Delphi 2010 - **all is normal**. I set a range in a design/real time. A result is fine in the both cases.

Does anybody have ideas?

Is this a bug or what?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Range` property  is deprecated instead you must use the the `Ranges` property.

Check this sample

```
uses
  IdHTTPHeaderInfo; 

var
  Range: TIdEntityRange;
begin
    Range := FHttp.Request.Ranges.Add;
    Range.StartPos := FRangeFrom;
    Range.EndPos := FRangeTo;
    FHttp.Get(FURL, FileStream);
end;
```

Comment: @maxfax: Indy 10's documentation is very outdated.  There have been a lot of features introduced and changes made since the documentation was last updated.

Answer (score 1):

Read this https://forums.embarcadero.com/thread.jspa?messageID=335670

How to set a range in Delphi XE:

```
idhttp1.Request.Ranges.Add.StartPos:=6000;
```

It's the same as

```
idHttp1.Request.Range:='6000-';
```