# Delphi "IdHTTP.Request.Range" propertie: undeclared identifier

Tags: delphi, download, resume, undeclared-identifier

I was looking for some tutorials/source codes to resume paused/aborted downloads.
I found a source code, but I'm getting this error:

```
procedure TForm1.Download(url, pathLocal : String);
var
   eFile     : TFileStream;
   IdHTTP  : TIdHTTP;

begin
   idHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);

   if FileExists(pathLocal) then //Caso o arquivo já exista ele o abre, caso contrário cria um novo
      eFile := TFileStream.Create(pathLocal,fmOpenReadWrite)
   else
      eFile := TFileStream.Create(pathLocal,fmCreate);

   try
      try
         eFile.Seek(0,soFromEnd); //Colocando o ponteiro no final do arquivo

         IdHTTP.Head(url); //Buscando informações do arquivo

         if eFile.Position < IdHTTP.Response.ContentLength then //Somente se o arquivo já não foi totalmente baixado
         begin
            IdHTTP.Request.ContentRangeStart := eFile.Position; //Definindo onde deve inciar o download
            IdHTTP.Request.ContentRangeEnd := IdHTTP.Response.ContentLength; //Verificando o tamanho do arquivo

            if eFile.Position > 0 then
            begin //É importante que o range seja definido com o tamanho inicial e o final
               IdHTTP.Request.Range := Format('%d-%d',[eFile.Position,IdHTTP.Response.ContentLength]); 
            end;

            IdHTTP.Get(url,eFile);
         end;
      except
         ShowMessage('Conexão interrompida.');
      end;
   finally
      eFile.Free;
      IdHTTP.Disconnect;
      IdHTTP.Free;
   end;
end;
```

This is the error:

```
Undeclared identifier: 'Range'
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

The `ContentRange...` properties are not used for HTTP requests, only HTTP responses. Take them out of your code completely.  Use only the `Range` property (which exists in Indy 10 so make sure you are not using Indy 9 or earlier).  As for the `Range` property itself, you are not formatting it correctly. It needs a `bytes=` prefix, and you can omit the end value to tell the server you want the rest of the file:

```
IdHTTP.Request.Range := Format('bytes=%d-',[eFile.Position]);
```

If you use the `Ranges` property instead, it handles those details for you (the `Range` property is deprecated):

```
IdHTTP.Request.Ranges.Add.StartPos := eFile.Position;
```

Before you send a ranged request, be sure to check if `Head()` set the `Response.AcceptRanges` property to `bytes` first, otherwise `Get()` could fail with an error or send you the entire file regardless of your specified range.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem it seems related to your indy version , try updating to the [last version of indy](http://indy.fulgan.com/) , also instead of `Request.Range` try  using `Request.Ranges` check this question for an example [Delphi XE: idHttp & Request.Range, a bug?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7202462/delphi-xe-idhttp-request-range-a-bug)

Comment: I've installed Indy 10, but this error continue..
I'm using Delphi 7..
Please help-me :(